# Abnormal Heap memory allocation in HTTP2

Tags: java, garbage-collection, nio, http2, eventsource

I am building a Messaging Service using Tomcat Server. I am also using HTTP2 network protocol (+ Nio) and  configured Tomcat Connector to use that. When tested with few users, my JVM heap increases exponentially. Inspecting the Heap Dump with MAT gives lot's of HTTP2 Stream processor class invoked while writing/reading data to Browser.

These Stream Processor class uses CharHeap and Byte Heap to write data to client. It's all good upto this but these Temporary objects continue to persist in Heap with the Stream processor class as it's Garbage Root. Since the HTTP2 connection will only destroy after user closing the page, the stream processor class object will also persist and so all the objects used for writing/reading data from/to browser continues to persist and increases heap memory

I am using ubuntu OS, tomcat v9.0.14, java v9.

MAT suspect Report gives

> 191 instances of "org.apache.coyote.http2.Stream", loaded by "java.net.URLClassLoader @ 0x6c01e4148" occupy 29,509,752 (61.19%) bytes.

My Tomcat Connector configuration is

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" > <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" /> 
/* Certificate options here*/
 </Connector>
```

Is it the default behaviour while using HTTP2 ? If so, is there any technique to reduce heap memory  (dereferencing objects from HTTP2 stream processor) ? or am i looking in the wrong direction ?